# Remove forked repo message from a (previously forked) repo on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on GitHub that used to be a fork, but it's no longer as I've wiped any trace of the original project and started a new project under the same name.

However, GitHub still indicates that the project is forked. Is there any way to remove the forked message you see on the project's page?

Answer (score 2):

Upon further investigation, I don't think this is possible. The best option is probably to [duplicate the repo](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repo).